# Diagram Chase: Ascending Chain of Kernels

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups, diagram-chasing

I have stumbled across what should be a routine diagram chase which I'm struggling with.

The question is as follows:

Let $f \colon A \to B$ be a map of Abelian groups. Let $p_A \colon A \to A$ and $p_B \colon B \to B$. Assume:

1. $ f \circ p_A = p_B \circ f $.
2. $A = \bigcup_{i \geq 1} \ker(p_A^i)$ and $B = \bigcup_{i \geq 1} \ker(p_B^i)$.
3. $f \colon \ker(p_A) \to \ker(p_B)$ is an isomorphism.
4. $f \colon \text{coker}(p_A) \to \text{coker}(p_B)$ is a monomorphism.

We want to show that $f$ is an isomorphism.

The book draws some diagrams (see below!) and claims the induction is straightforward, but I cannot even seem to show that $\ker(p_A^2) \to \ker(p_B^2)$ is an isomorphism.

[image]

EDIT(s): The book suppresses the subscript on the $p$. One should interpret the upper row as dealing with $p_A$ and the lower row as dealing with $p_B$. Presumably one should successively show that $f|_{\ker(p_A^i)} \colon {\ker(p_A^i)} \to {\ker(p_B^i)}$ is an isomorphism, although this is not stated explicitly.

There seems to be a typo: $\ker(p)/p\ker(A)$ doesn't make sense, and neither does $\ker(p)/pB$ now that I think about it! Needless to say, I'm even more confused!

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun This is from a set of notes by Haynes Miller simply titled "Notes on Cobordism". I also happen to know that this proof is lifted from page 487 in the paper "Periodic Phenomena in the Adams-Novikov Spectral Sequence" by Miller-Ravenel-Wilson.

Comment: Inductive step for what? What is the claim? And what is $p$, you only write $p_A$ and $p_B$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I've edited the question, hopefully it clears up the misunderstanding.

Comment: It's still not clear what should be proven by induction. The statement that $f$ is an isomorphism does not contain any variable from $\mathbb{N}$. Also, it is strange that the displayed diagrams contain $p^2$.

Comment: Direct proof that $f$ is injective: Let $f(a)=0$. By 2. have $a \in \ker(p_A^i)$ for some $i \geq 0$. If $i=0$, $p_A^0 = \mathrm{id}_A$ and we are done. Otherwise $i > 0$. Consider $a' := p_A^{i-1}(a)$. It is contained in $\ker(p_A)$, and by 2. we have $f(a')=p_B^{i-1}(f(a))=0$. Then 3. implies $a'=0$, so $a \in \ker(p_A^{i-1})$. So we are done by induction.

Comment: Probably you can cook up a direct proof that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Ah you're perfectly correct! I think I got a bit overzealous with following some elaborate diagram. Let me mess around with surjectivity. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what was intended:
$\newcommand{cok}{\text{cok}}$
$\require{AMScd}$

The proof is by induction; we claim that for each $n \geq 1$, the map
$\ker (p^{n}) \to \ker (p^{n})$ is an isomorphism and the map $\cok
(p^{n}) \to \cok (p^{n})$ is a monomorphism (with the apparent subscripts omitted — I believe that in the original setting, they just referred to multiplying by a prime number $p$, for what that's worth). We know that these are true when $n=1$.

The inductive step: for each $n \geq 1$, the following are commutative
diagrams with exact rows; the vertical maps are all given by $f$:
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \ker(p^{n-1}) @>>> \ker(p^{n}) @>{p^{n-1}}>> \ker(p) @>>> \ker(p)/p^{n-1} \ker(p^{n})
@>{\text{1-1}}>> \cok(p^{n-1}) \\
@. @VV{\cong}V @VVV @VV{\cong}V @VVV @VV{\text{1-1}}V\\
0 @>>> \ker(p^{n-1}) @>>> \ker(p^{n}) @>{p^{n-1}}>> \ker(p) @>>> \ker(p)/p^{n-1} \ker(p^{n})
@>{\text{1-1}}>> \cok(p^{n-1})
\end{CD}
and
\begin{CD}
\ker (p^{n-1})/p \ker (p^{n}) @>>> \cok (p) @>{p^{n-1}}>> \cok (p^{n}) @>>> \cok (p^{n-1}) @>>> 0 \\
@VVV @VV{\text{1-1}}V @VVV @VV{\text{1-1}}V \\
\ker (p^{n-1})/p \ker (p^{n}) @>>> \cok (p) @>{p^{n-1}}>> \cok (p^{n}) @>>> \cok (p^{n-1}) @>>> 0\\
\end{CD}
The first diagram and the five lemma imply that $\ker (p^{n}) \to \ker
(p^{n})$ is an isomorphism. Then the left-hand vertical map in the
second diagram is an isomorphism, so one of the four lemmas (as
described on [Wikipedia's Five lemma page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma)) implies that $\cok (p^{n})
\to \cok (p^{n})$ is a monomorphism.

Comment: Thanks! What a beautiful answer :) In retrospect I didn't catch the obvious fact gleaned from the first diagram that the compositions of the two monomorphisms on the right means that the map between the twos ker(p)/p^{n-1} is also a monomorphism (I'll be kicking myself for the rest of the evening). That same map is a surjection by inspection and voilà, the 5 lemma does the job. I don't think I would've remembered that particular 4 lemma though!

Comment: By the way, there is at least one other typo in those notes: the map $cok(p^2) \to cok(p)$ is not one-to-one, but rather onto.